# Three-constraint homogeneous QCQP

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Consider the homogeneous quadratically constrained quadratic program,
$$\min_{u^T u =1} u^T A_1 u$$
$$\textrm{subject to}\quad u^T A_2 u = 0,\quad u^T A_3 u = 0$$
This problem is particularly studied in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0104.pdf (specifically page 6) and they give a reformulation as
$$\max_{\lambda,t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb{R}} \lambda$$
$$\textrm{subject to}\quad A_1 + t_1 A_2 + t_2 A_3 - \lambda I \succeq 0$$
which is an efficiently solvable semidefinite program (SDP). Unfortunately, after trying to apply this technique, it seems to me that their reduction is incorrect.

(The reduction in the first case (with no $A_3$) is correct, but their argument fails when $A_3\neq 0$, because you can have $u^T A_2 u < 0$ while $u^T A_3 u > 0$, and indeed this happens in the case I'm trying to apply it. The result ends up being equivalent to the original SDP relaxation, (3) in their paper. I need to figure out if I should try contacting them about this issue, but the paper is 8 years old already...)

Anyway, I would like to solve this problem. I've searched a good deal and found results that deal with two quadratic constraints at a time, but never three. I'm aware that having an *arbitrary* number of quadratic constraints in NP-hard, so I expect that any solution must either be very specific to three constraints in particular, or must have a complexity that grows exponentially with the number of quadratic constraints.

As one more note, some equivalent versions of the problem I care about are:

- A convex objective with three concave constraints (that is, $u^T A_i u < c$, with $A \succeq 0$)
- A concave objective with three convex constraints (constraints like $u^T A_i u > c$ with $A_i \succeq 0$, but objective $u^T B u$ with $B \preceq 0$).

Any pointers on how to reformulate this in a convex way would be very appreciated.

Comment: In the case you mention ($A_2<0$, $A_3>0$), the minimum is taken over the empty set, so it is formally $+\infty$, just as the formula predicts. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit terse. You can have some u1 where both are negative, a u2 where one is negative and the other is positive, and another u3 where both are positive. There are optimal u's such that u.A1.u = 0, and optimal u's such that u.A2.u = 0, but no optimal u's such that both occur simultaneously. This circumvents the logic of their proof.